# Calculating SUM on 3 related tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I have three tables that are in 1-to-many relationships. Since my business scenario is not easy to explain, I am going to use a more familiar terms:

Customers -> Invoices -> InvoiceDetails

Lets assume that there exist Customers.Value1, Invoices.Value2, InvoiceDetails.Value3, all of type double (real).

I need to get the summaries of Value1, Value2 and Value3 for all records which contain customers from particular country (in reality my where clause has much more conditions, but all conditions relate to Customers table only).

A 3-query example of the values I need would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(c.Value1) FROM Customers c WHERE c.Country = <cond>
SELECT SUM(i.Value2) FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Invoices i ON c.Id = i.CustomerId WHERE c.Country = <cond>
SELECT SUM(d.Value2) FROM (Customers c INNER JOIN Invoices i ON c.Id = i.CustomerId) INNER JOIN InvoiceDetails d ON i.Id = d.InvoiceId WHERE c.Country = <cond>
```

Now imagine if my WHERE clause is much complex, then repeating this WHERE clause three times looks very bad and is error prone. Also, in this example we filter the records 3 times in a same manner

Is there a way to avoid repeating WHERE clause, and do this in a single query?

**Edit**: based on the answers which suggest to do all three summaries in a join query, let me provide data to explain why is this incorrect.

```
Customers from Spain:
Customer1  Value1 = 10
Customer2  Value1 = 20

Invoices for customers from Spain:
Invoice1  Customer1 Value2 = 100
Invoice2  Customer1 Value2 = 200
Invoice3  Customer2 Value2 = 300
Invoice4  Customer2 Value2 = 400

SELECT SUM(c.Value1) FROM Customers c WHERE c.Country = "Spain"
returns 30

SELECT SUM(c.Value1), SUM(i.Value2) FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Invoices i ON c.Id = i.CustomerId WHERE c.Country = "Spain"
returns 60, 1000
```

As you can see, the result for Customer summary was incorrect due to joined records.

Comment: why can't you do one single `join`ed query and sum them all at once? just `group by` as appropriate

Comment: @MarcB well, if I added SUM(c.Value1) in second query, then the summary would be incorrect for Value1, due to repeated value in joined query

Comment: This is EF, right? Why don't you use navigation properties and let EF create the SQL query for you?

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you give an example?

Comment: What is the **type** of `c.Value1`, `i.Value2` and `d.Value2` - `int`, `decimal` or ?

Comment: @IvanStoev Its Sql Server real (c# double)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using EF, you can define and use navigation properties instead of joins. For instance:

```
public class Customer
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<InvoiceDetail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use simple LINQ To Entities query like this (since you want multiple aggregates, the query uses *group by constant* technique):

```
var query = 
    from c in db.Customers
    where c.Country = <cond>
    group c by 1 into g
    selec new
    {
        Value1 = g.Sum(c => (double?)c.Value1) ?? 0,
        Value2 = g.SelectMany(c => c.Invoices).Sum(i => (double?)i.Value2) ?? 0,
        Value3 = g.SelectMany(c => c.Invoices).SelectMany(i => i.Details).Sum(d => (double?)d.Value2) ?? 0,
    };
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

The `nullable` casts are needed in order to avoid `Sum` exception when the corresponding set is empty.

**Update:** The above doesn't produce good SQL. It's strange how the way you write the LINQ query affects the generated SQL query (I have a feeling I'm back in the days when we were controlling the SQL query execution plan the way we write the query). Here is the alternative LINQ query:

```
var query =
    from c in db.Customers
    where c.Country == "BG"
    let Value1 = (double?)c.Value1
    let Value2 = c.Invoices.Sum(i => (double?)i.Value2)
    let Value3 = c.Invoices.SelectMany(i => i.Details).Sum(i => (double?)i.Value2)
    group new { Value1, Value2, Value3 } by 1 into g
    select new
    {
        Value1 = g.Sum(e => e.Value1),
        Value2 = g.Sum(e => e.Value2),
        Value3 = g.Sum(e => e.Value3),
    };
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

which generates something closer to the expected:

```
SELECT
    [Limit1].[K1] AS [C1],
    [Limit1].[A1] AS [C2],
    [Limit1].[A2] AS [C3],
    [Limit1].[A3] AS [C4]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1)
        [Project2].[K1] AS [K1],
        SUM([Project2].[A1]) AS [A1],
        SUM([Project2].[A2]) AS [A2],
        SUM([Project2].[A3]) AS [A3]
        FROM ( SELECT
            1 AS [K1],
            [Project2].[Value1] AS [A1],
            [Project2].[C1] AS [A2],
            [Project2].[C2] AS [A3]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Project1].[Value1] AS [Value1],
                [Project1].[C1] AS [C1],
                (SELECT
                    SUM([Extent4].[Value2]) AS [A1]
                    FROM  [dbo].[Invoice] AS [Extent3]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[InvoiceDetail] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent4].[Invoice_Id]
                    WHERE [Project1].[Id] = [Extent3].[Customer_Id]) AS [C2]
                FROM ( SELECT
                    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
                    [Extent1].[Value1] AS [Value1],
                    (SELECT
                        SUM([Extent2].[Value2]) AS [A1]
                        FROM [dbo].[Invoice] AS [Extent2]
                        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Customer_Id]) AS [C1]
                    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
                    WHERE N'BG' = [Extent1].[Country]
                )  AS [Project1]
            )  AS [Project2]
        )  AS [Project2]
        GROUP BY [K1]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

Comment: The problem is that this query is not optimized - and that is the problem that I was talking about with multiple filtering of the same recordset - query produced by your code will filter customers table three times. In my scenario I need to summarize 1 field on Customers, 7 fields on Invoices and 10 fields on Products. According to my measured results L2E query is approx 15-20x slower than the SQL query which filters customers in temp table, and then executes 3 queries that I provided in question. This is really inefficient.

Comment: Agree. L2E queries are highly limited and dependant of the SQL translation. Updated with a better SQL query, can't say what will be the performance.

Comment: Thank you, that query produces much better sql.